# Can't bubblesort these values

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I'll try to keep this short and simple. Here's my assignment (too big to copy here):

[Exercise picture 1][2] 
[Exercise picture 2][1]

So long story short, I've created a new data style that will hold 3 values (a,b and c) and these have to be put into an equation and then it will calc the roots and display it. 
I'm not nearly finished yet but i've got some problems with sorting the values (which we have to do)

Comment: Side note- you should create a swap function, rather than repeating the exact same code multiple times in your sort_equation_array function

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I believe that if you initialize pass to 0, initialize i to (pass + 1), replace all V[i] with V[pass], and all V[i+1] with V[i], your code should work as expected

Comment: another thing what do you want to sort? do you want to sort a, b, c of struct or the array???!!

Comment: @Raindrop7 I want to sort the values of the struct, first by values of a. and it should then it should categorize all equations if they have one root, two roots or complex roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

> I believe that if you initialize pass to 0, initialize i to (pass + 1), replace all V[i] with V[pass], and all V[i+1] with V[i], your code should work as expected

```
void swap(Quadratic_equation arr[], int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
    Quadratic_equation temp = arr[lowerIndex];
    arr[lowerIndex] = arr[higherIndex];
    arr[higherIndex] = temp;
}
void sort_equation_array(Quadratic_equation V[], int howMany)
{
     for ( int pass = 0; pass < howMany; pass++ )
       {                   

         for (int i = (pass + 1); i <= howMany -1; i++)     
         {
             if (V[pass].a > V[i].a)
             {
                 swap(V, pass, i);
             }
             else if (V[pass].a == V[i].a &&
                      V[pass].b > V[i].b)
             {
                 swap(V, pass, i);
             }
             else if (V[pass].a == V[i].a &&
                 V[pass].b == V[i].b &&
                 V[pass].c > V[i].c)
             {
                 swap(V, pass, i);
             }
         }
      }
}
```

You should also clean up your input to make it easier to tell which values are going where. Here's what I did, you can change it to say whatever you'd like, but you get the idea.

```
void get_quadratic_equation(Quadratic_equation &e)
{
    cout << "a: ";
    cin >> e.a;
    cout << "b: ";
    cin >> e.b;
    cout << "c: ";
    cin >> e.c;
}

int load_equation(Quadratic_equation V[], int n)
{
     Quadratic_equation e;

     int counter = 0; 
     cout << endl << "Set values for equation " << counter << endl;
     get_quadratic_equation(e); 

     while (e.a != 0)
     {
         V[counter] = e; 
         ++counter;

         if (counter == n) break;
         cout << endl << "Set values for equation " << counter << endl;
         get_quadratic_equation(e); 
     }
     cout << endl;
     return counter;
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
** Enter Quadratic Equations **

Set values for equation 0
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3

Set values for equation 1
a: 4
b: 5
c: 6

Set values for equation 2
a: 7
b: 8
c: 9

Set values for equation 3
a: 8
b: 7
c: 6

Set values for equation 4
a: 5
b: 4
c: 3

Set values for equation 5
a: 2
b: 1
c: 0

Set values for equation 6
a: 0
b: 0
c: 0

** NOT SORTED **
1x^2 + 2x + 3     root 1 = -1.00+i 1.41       root 2 = -1.00-i 1.41
4x^2 + 5x + 6     root 1 = 0.00+i 1.05       root 2 = 0.00-i 1.05
7x^2 + 8x + 9     root 1 = 0.00+i 0.98       root 2 = 0.00-i 0.98
8x^2 + 7x + 6     root 1 = 0.00+i 0.75       root 2 = 0.00-i 0.75
5x^2 + 4x + 3     root 1 = 0.00+i 0.66       root 2 = 0.00-i 0.66
2x^2 + 1x + 0     root 1 = 0.00       root 2 = -0.50

** SORTED BY A **
1x^2 + 2x + 3     root 1 = -1.00+i 1.41       root 2 = -1.00-i 1.41
2x^2 + 1x + 0     root 1 = 0.00       root 2 = -0.50
4x^2 + 5x + 6     root 1 = 0.00+i 1.05       root 2 = 0.00-i 1.05
5x^2 + 4x + 3     root 1 = 0.00+i 0.66       root 2 = 0.00-i 0.66
7x^2 + 8x + 9     root 1 = 0.00+i 0.98       root 2 = 0.00-i 0.98
8x^2 + 7x + 6     root 1 = 0.00+i 0.75       root 2 = 0.00-i 0.75
```

Comment: @SamuelSvensson I checked the equations in the exercise, and my code correctly bubble sorts them. As far as your other assignment requirements (grouping, formatting, etc.), those are beyond the scope of this question

Comment: @SamuelSvensson If my answer helped you solve your bubble sort question, please upvote and mark as the accepted answer so future viewers can identify working solutions. Unfortunately I am not a tutor, and I do not have the time to work one-on-one with questions of much larger scope. I'm not the only fish in the sea, though, I'm sure many more people on here would be happy to help you.  Feel free to post additional questions in separate questions. And remember, to get help on SO, you need to ask *specific questions* outlining a *specific problem* and how you've attempted to solve it.